# Angular 10 Fullcalendar - How to edit event title, content and how to delete event?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using Angular 10, and fullcalendar 5.5.1, and trying to understand how the API works. I found some install steps on this [blog](https://therichpost.com/angular-10-fullcalendar-list-view-working-example/?unapproved=63169&moderation-hash=893370a12c29cde656bee6a92394756f#comment-63169), it works as-is (see screenshot below), but now I need to edit and delete events.

I thought I'd experiment by first trying to delete the two events that I've added. Since the next button `>` is calling `next()` fine, I'd like to delete the events there, and later hook it into an actual delete button click handler. The `this.$calendarRef.fullCalendar` call is erroring out because fullCalendar is not a function. the Ref has many functions, but fullCalendar isn't one of them. (I used this technique back in nG 5, thought it might work with the latest FC).

Can someone please help me get started?

**screenshot:**

[image: Fullcalendar Screenshot]

**component.ts:**

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarService } from '../calendar.service';
import { CalendarOptions } from '@fullcalendar/angular';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'calendar-widget',
  templateUrl: './calendar-widget.component.html',
})

export class CalendarWidgetComponent implements OnDestroy {

  private $calendarRef: any;
  private calendar: any;
  public period = 'Showing'

  public calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,listWeek'
    },
    editable: true,
    selectable: false,
    unselectAuto: false,
    droppable: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [
      { title: 'event 1', date: '2021-01-12'},
      { title: 'event 2', date: '2021-01-21'}
    ]
  };

  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef, 
    private calendarService: CalendarService
  ) {
  }
  
  public next() {
    console.log("CalendarWidgetComponent next");

    this.$calendarRef = $(document.getElementById('full-calendar'));
    this.$calendarRef.fullCalendar('removeEvents');  //<<<<< ERROR this.$calendarRef.fullCalendar is not a function

    $('.fc-next-button', this.el.nativeElement).click();
  }

  public prev() {
    $('.fc-prev-button', this.el.nativeElement).click();
  }
}
```

**component.html:**

```
<div sa-widget color="blueDark">
  <header>
    <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> </span>

    <h2> My Events </h2>

    <div class="widget-toolbar">
      <div class="btn-group" dropdown>
        <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" dropdownToggle>
          {{period}} <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
          <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="changeView('month')">Month</a></li>
          <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="changeView('agendaWeek')">Agenda</a></li>
          <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" (click)="changeView('agendaDay')">Today</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div>
    <div class="widget-body no-padding">
      <div class="widget-body-toolbar">
        <div id="calendar-buttons">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a (click)="prev()" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a (click)="next()" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <full-calendar [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `this.$calendarRef.fullCalendar('removeEvents');` this is a fullCalendar 3 jQuery syntax. If you're using the read-made Angular component provided by fullCalendar (and if not, why not?) then go to its documentation at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular and scroll down until you find the section called "Calendar API". Instructions are there about how to access the fullCalendar object to call methods.

Comment: Your API doc link solved it. I am using the nG component provided by fullCalendar, but me being at FC v6.14.10, and the latest docs at v5.5.1, was confusing before I posted. I was having some errors, so I figured it was due not using the correct API. Thanks.

Comment: There isn't a fullCalendar 6. Possibly that's the version of the Ng component it's wrapped in. 5.5. is the latest version of fullCalendar itself. Glad you were able to resolve it anyway

Comment: I was using: $npm -v @fullcalendar
6.14.10

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fullcalendar only lists up to 5.5.1. I would expect `npm -v` to return your version of npm itself, not the version of a particular package (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-version - so far as I can see you can't pass in a package name as an argument).

Comment: Sorry, my dumb mistake. The actual usage is: $npm view fullcalendar version
5.5.1
Thanks. I'll fix my original question.